# Traceback (most recent call last): File "./prog.py", line 5, in <module> IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

```
for i in range(int(input())):
N = int(input())
A = list(map(int,input().split()))
holidays = 8
if A[i]==6 or A[i]==7 or A[i]==13 or A[i]==14 or A[i]==20 or A[i]==21 or A[i]==27 or A[i]==28:
    holidays-=1
    print(holidays)
else:
    print(holidays+N)
```

Input:
3
2
5 7
3
23 1 6
1
13

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./prog.py", line 5, in 
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "./prog.py", line 5, in IndexError: list index out of range` implies that the index that you're trying to access in a list doesn't have an item.

You could check the content of the list with `print(A)` and check the values of A[6], A[7] and A[13]. There's a big workaround there.